# How do I publish my Visual Studio Angular project using Yarn instead of Npm?

Tags: angular, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a Visual Studio Angular project that I'm trying to deploy via Azure DevOps Pipelines and I want the Angular code in the ClientApp folder to be built using Yarn instead of Npm.

I have a .Net Core task in the pipeline that publishes my web project and also tries to build the Angular code in the ClientApp folder using Npm - and fails.

I need to either change the Publish step for the Visual Studio project somehow so it uses Yarn, or I need to disable/prevent the Publish step from building my Angular code at all so that I can just use a separate Yarn step in the pipeline to build the Angular code in the ClientApp folder independently from the server-side code. How can I do this?

Comment: In the `.csprog` configured to run `npm run build`?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk, yes you're right. That was what I ended up changing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to edit my project file and change the entries for npm to use yarn. Simple as that

```
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="yarn install" />
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="yarn build-prod" />
```

"build-prod" is an entry that I defined in the `scripts` section of my package.json